# PHP Regex: Trouble identifying if next sub-pattern starts another pattern

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to extract this data from a file but the thing is, at the point where I'm stuck, there could be a whole new pattern (that starts with a date), or there could be a complemente in the route (which does not start with a digit).

I'm having trouble identifying whether or not the next digit is a new pattern or a complement. I also haven't been able to optimize this pattern, as you can see after the EQPT mark.

Examples of strings to match:

```
291011 311011 1234560 AZU4059 E190/M SBKP1513 N0458 350 DCT BGC DCT TRIVI DCT CNF UW58      SBRF0249 EQPT/WRG PBN/D1O1 EET/SBRE0107 SAGAZ/N0454F370 UW58 GEBIT UW10

271011 UFN    1230060 AZU4062 E190/M SBPA2140 N0460 350 UM540 OSAMU DCT NEGUS UW47          SBKP0120 EQPT/WRG PBN/D1O1 EET/SBBS0106
```

My regex so far:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-3][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-9]{2})\s*(UFN|[0-3][0-9][0|1][0-9][0-9]{2})\s*([0-7]{7})\s*(AZU[0-9]{4})\s*([A-Z0-9]{4})\/([L|M|H])\s*([A-Z0-9]{8})\s*(N[0-9]{4})\s*([0-9]{3})\s*([\S\s]{1,40})\s*([A-Z0-9]{8})\s*(EQPT\/WR?G?\s?P?B?N?\/?D?1?O?1?\s?E?E?T?\/?([A-Z0-9]{8})?)\s*)/', $result, $match);
```

Comment: Could you also add - example match output?

Comment: it outputs the same thing, execpt it organizes them into a table

Comment: As I see it now you have a blank line which you could use as delimiter. Is this the case?

Comment: not really... they are actually not in new lines, they are just followed by blank spaces... in the examples of strings to match, i just separeted them to be easier to see that the first one has a complement and the second one finishes at SBBS0106

Comment: Well then my friend you have a problem. You have to find the "entry" point of your regex. Where does the matching starts and stops? Hardcoding everything in a regex - just like you did - is not a good practice. Change a character and your regex fails.

Comment: it's actually matching all 413 matches I need, but I'm just missing the route complement, that is between the end of a match and the beggining of another one.. I don't really think it's that difficult, just didn't figure out what I'm missing yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I had to do many things to make this work:

I removed all the blank double spaces and replaced all of the first sub-pattern dates by "######". I also replaced and second parameters by "UFN" and mapped the ones I replace with a couple of arrays.

Then I added a # at the end and used it at the end of the regex pattern, so that it would be certain that it would start a new pattern when it came to a #. And it all worked out, I then just had to reposition the rest of the route so that it would complement the other one.

Thank you for trying to help!